# inner div needs to be 100% height

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-container">
    </div>

    <div id="right-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

The container is 100% height (I checked it with Firebug). But the `#left_container` needs to be 100% too and it isn't!

Below is my CSS and a [screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1056571/screenshot.png). The yellow should be 100%. Yellow is the background of the `#left-container`

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height:100%;
    background: #fff;
}
#left-container {
    width: 300px;
    background: #ff0;
    height:100%;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This article discusses both the issue and solution in detail:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

This might help too:

```css
#outer {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#inner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='inner'>
  </div>
  text
</div>
```

See here for more details on the above:
[How to make a floated div 100% height of its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049783/how-to-make-a-floated-div-100-height-of-its-parent)

Comment: My eye is twitching over your use of single quotes in your HTML... except it might just be me winking in approval over how you subtly added a single space in the #outer css so that the two lines are the exact same width.  I'm so torn.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this problem is to think outside the box a little. There's no reason that both containers need to stretch to 100% if you're just concerned about the background stretching for both of them. There's a really simple technique called [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) in which you combine the backgrounds for both sidebars into one single background image, and set the main container's background to that image. When a longer sidebar stretches the main container, it brings down the background for both sidebars.

Answer (score 0):

```css
   
<style>
    #outer-container {
        height:200vh;
        width:100%;
         position:relative;
        background-color:orange;
    }
    #left-container{
        position:absolute;
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
        background-color:blue;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<body>

    <div id="outer-container">
        <div id="left-container">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You should be able to use just

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
```

For the conatainers to get what you want.