# Solid solution for div/body height 100%

Tags: html, css

I think we need to find a solid solution for this problem - on the internet, there does not seem to be one.

The DIV will always stay the height of its content - and not more.

The structure is like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>myPage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            Some Content...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS usually looks like this:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}
div#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

There are already tricks with setting margin or/and padding on body or/and div, but nothing seems to work really fine.

**Is there a one and only solution for this problem?**

Comment: This has to be the most asked question on SO for html/css. I apologize that my comment's not helpful, but the Related list of questions on the right should prove immensely helpful.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking? Should it have it's content height or should it have the height of the window?

Comment: Does anyone know what the question is? He is basically just showing us a div that covers the entire screen. What isn't working as expected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does 100% not mean 100% height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880365/why-does-100-not-mean-100-height)

Comment: The answer before was just the right one - if you do NOT define html height: 100%, it **wont't** work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
html, body, div#container{
   min-height: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

May be this will help?

Comment: Also works without min-height, but thank you - I forgot the HTML element ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding:0; }
#container { height: auto; min-height:100%; background:#ccc; }
```

Comment: some explanation will make it more useful.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Background image display full screen after include this css property because background cut between debugging code from footer.