# CSS stretching to 100% Height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to accomplish something very simple. My poor rusty CSS skills do not help one bit.

This is want to achieve:
[image]

I cannot make it happen. If I use `height: 100%` it works when there isn't much  text, but when I add a lot of Lorem Ipsum, the content div gets stretched and the left menu div doesn't scale with it.

I don't want to use JavaScript, just clean CSS if it's that's possible.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="menu">Menu</div>
<div id="content">Content (paste a lot of lorem ipsum here and menu doesn't stretch)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
}
#header
{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#menu
{
    width: 225px;
    float: left;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#content
{
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: flex box is what your looking for. - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It's actually not as simple as you think, and this is common design request asked by many, that is not straight forward or 'out-of-the-box'

Comment: The appearance you desire **seems simple**, but is not.  You're asking a lot of the browser.  And, height 100% does not do what you think it does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880365/why-does-100-not-mean-100-height.  Lastly, you don't want 100% - you want 100% *minus the height of your header*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Ayhpg)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #bada55;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: #c0ffee;
}
aside {
  width: 150px;
  background: darkgoldenrod;
}
main {
  min-height: 100%;
  /*height: 2000px;*/  /* uncomment this to see difference */
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<section>
  <aside></aside>
  <main></main>
</section>
```

Comment: Will this always stretch to the bottom of the browser window?

Comment: Yes it will. Try It. Note, I haven't set a height on either the sicebar or the main content are other than `min- height:100%`. The sidebar always adjusts to the height of the main section.

Comment: It should be noted that this code example doesn't include them, but it's probably recommended to use all the vendor prefixes.  In my experience, it gets verbose, but has good browser support *unless you care about IE9*: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: I don't include vendor prefixes unless asked. The user is capable of searching for those themselves but if necessary they are availlable in the Codepen by viewing the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 1):

try to give height relative to viewport height. **vh**

```
   height:100vh;
```

Comment: Does this work? Do you have a fiddle that demonstrates it? If so, this is an excellent solution.  How does it accomodate the header space?

Comment: With lot of content this does not work - https://jsfiddle.net/kysaws32/1/