# How to override relative positioning on Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, umbraco7

I have tried to add a Google Map to my Umbraco site using the code below. The Div `#map_canvas` gets relative positioning from the api and as such doesn't display on the page. If I manually override this in the inspector with static positioning the map appears, but I have tried in various ways to permanently override this, using suggestions found elsewhere on Stack Overflow, but have had no success. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

EDIT: Turnip, this is as close as I can get, given that the page inherits some Umbraco code and is displaying in Umbraco's preview window, but I assume that the problem wouldn't be there anyway.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.MasterTemplate2>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
@{
Layout = null;
}<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>"testpage"</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/wsha-style.css">

<script src="~/umbraco/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAbVhWKXQ2uj-n0lX1JsZh_DqG9RI-XDhE"></script>

</head>

<body>


<div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%;"></div>



<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var map_position = new google.maps.LatLng(55.8735958,-4.3387407)

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: map_position,
        zoom: 3
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map_position,
        map: map,
        title: 'Marker'
    });

});


</script>

</body>
```

Comment: I can't imagine why relative positioning would stop the map from displaying. Could you create a [MCVE] showing the issue?

Comment: [height](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property). Short answer: replace `height: 100%` with `height: 100vh` or px you want. See more at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880365/why-does-100-not-mean-100-height)

Comment: @Hikarunomemory - that worked! Thank you. Can you post as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: replace height: 100% with height: 100vh or px you want.

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to 'auto'.

See more at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880365/why-does-100-not-mean-100-height)

For further reading: [the height property from W3C recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any position in your map DIV,, but you should first give a different position to your parent DIV, example:

```
#parentDIV {
 position: relative;
}
#map_canvas {
 position: absolute
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this is relevant. I can't give any positioning to my div, it is being determined for me by the google code. I have tried putting another div around the `#map_canvas' div and changing the positioning on that but that doesn't help.