# The height of div element is not setting automatically

Tags: html, css

```
               .block    
               {
                width:540px;
                margin:20px;
                padding:10px;
                border:1px solid Gray;
               }

              <div id="header" class="block">
                <div id="pe" class="text">
                  <b>Name :</b> <span>King</span><br />
                  <b>Surname :</b> <span>Kong</span>
                </div>
                <div id="area" class="text">
                  <span id="city">Abcs</span><b>/</b>
                  <span id="state">Bcsdf</span>
                </div>
              </div>​
```

If u run the above code in Jsfiddle, then it shows a `border around the text` and `the important thing is that` the `height of the block class is auto`, so it automatically adjust its height.

But the problem comes when i added the following css :

```
 #pe
 {
  float:left;
 }
 #area
 {
   float:right;
 }​
```

Now the height of `div.block` is not set automatically. Can anybody tell me the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now You need a Clearfix for it

```
.clearfix:after{
clear:both;
line-height:0;
height:0;
display:block;
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
content: ".";
visibility:hidden;
 }

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
height: 1%;
 }
```

you add it like this

```
"<div id = "header" class="block clearfix"></div>"
```

Answer (score 2):

add float:left; in your block class.

Answer (score 1):

because float takes them out of the current flow. They are not inside the block div in the same way they where, use positioning and display:inline to get them to line up the way you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute positioning where by the outer element is set to height:auto and the inner #pe and #area are set to height:100%.

Have a look at this answer: [How to make a floated div 100% height of its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3050064/977431)

Answer (score 1):

That's because they're not part of the common flow of the document anymore.

The solution could be to set `display: block` in the block class and then use `position: absolute` to position the element within that block by using `left: 0` and `right: 0`

Answer (score 1):

Just add overflow:hidden to class "block".

```
 .block{
   width:540px;
   margin:20px;
   padding:10px;
   border:1px solid Gray;
   overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rWuBF/

Answer (score 1):

I would add `overflow:hidden` to the containing element (`#header`). That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit dirtier, you can also add something that clears both after the floated elements.

```
<div id="header" class="block">
  <div id="pe" class="text"> ... </div>

  <div id="area" class="text"> ... </div>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

There are also cleaner "clearfix" variations of this as well, that will let you clear:both without adding non-semantic markup.
http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html