# How to float an element left with full height of the wrapper?

Tags: css, css-float, floating

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        Foo
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Text row 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        Foo Bar
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Text row 1<br>
        Text row 2<br>
        Text row 3
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.left {
    width:80px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
```

How can I give the floating div the full height of the wrapper (whose height is varying)?

is it possible without jQuery?

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6B43/

Comment: I actually have the same problem, I only managed to do it with jQuery. I'd be glad to know if it's possible otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a floated div 100% height of its parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049783/how-to-make-a-floated-div-100-height-of-its-parent)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### The `display: table` solution

Within tables each cell of a row has the same height.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.left, .right {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

This is the best solution in my opinion, but is [not compatible before IE8](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TYpfK/) for this solution.

### Using absolute positioning

Absolute positioned elements respect their relative parents `height`:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 85px;
}
.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Normally I would **not** recommend absolute positioning in most situations. But as you have a fixed `width` anyway, **maybe** it does not matter. But be aware of the fact that this will ignore long contents in `.left`. The height is just controlled by `.right`.

Here is an [update to your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6B43/9/).

### The `flex`ible solution

<del>This is so new I would not recommend using it right now, but just to be complete.</del> You could use CSS3 [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), but be aware of [browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox):

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```

The [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kU6zx/4/) (tested in current Chrome and Firefox).

### The `grid` layout

Even newer than flexbox, CSS [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) seams to be the perfect answer for layout questions.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'left right';
}

.left {
    grid-area: left;
}

.right {
    grid-area: right;
}
```

[Browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) is rare, if you go back a view versions. Besides, it would be overkill for the OP's scenario in my opinion, but for more complex layout troubles in the future, this is a very powerful thing.

See it in the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zw9x6yc/).

Comment: Just because an element has a fixed width doesn't mean absolute positioning is safe to use; it is the length of the element that causes problems.

Comment: @cimmanon, I agree. That's why I posted alternatives. But in the given example the only problem is the content of the right `<div/>`. So please let me dream that Martin knows for sure the left content is one line anytime. ;-) In that case, it would do the job I think. Not true?

Comment: I can't imagine very many instances where an instance of equal height columns has a single line's worth of content in one of the columns.  Would be an inefficient layout if that were the case.  It is always safest to assume that either/any column could be the taller one because it is the most likely scenario.

Comment: @cimmanon, well, I reordered and modified my answer and tried to meet your correct objection.

Comment: Thanks, the solutions work here. Table and fixed wrapper heights are not possible.

Comment: If you use top: 0 and bottom: 0 on the absolute positioning solution, the column will stretch to match the height of his relative parent.

Comment: BTW, this layout is called "faux columns" ans is discussed on alistapart.com and I'm sure smashing magazine has an article about this too. Just google it.

Answer (score -10):

Add:

```
body, html { height:100% }
```

And give your wrapper a fixed height in pixels.