# Dynamic height for a child div when the position is relative

Tags: html, css

It seems a duplicated question but unfortunately I didn't find answers for this simple scenario when the `Position` is `Relative`.

I have a parent div with two child divs:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="content_rdivider">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="content_right"></div>
</div>
```

where both parent and child divs have a `position:relative;`

A Jsfiddle example is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9c4MK/21/)

So my question is almost like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049783/how-to-make-a-floated-div-100-height-of-its-parent) question but the position is not absolute here.

How do I make the height of `content_rdivider` div the same as the height of the parent div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/9c4MK/15/

CSS

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 975px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom left;
    border: solid 1px #d7d7d7;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    direction: ltr;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    display: table;
}
#content_right {
    width: 180px;
    text-align: right;
    display: table-cell;
}
#content_rdivider {
    width: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: @Fags, Thanks for your answer, However it's not working when a float is there, please check out [This](http://jsfiddle.net/9c4MK/21/)

Comment: @Ala ==> float:left remove in this class #content_rdivider its working perfectly please try http://jsfiddle.net/9c4MK/22/