# css - top going past parent element

Tags: html, css-position, css

I am using the top attribute to make a div begin at the top of its parent and end at the bottom.  The bottom part is working.  For some reason though, the top is beginning two parents back.  Here is my code:

```
<div class="right">
    <div class="boxx details-history">
        <div class="boxx-content">
            Box content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxx details-coursework">
        <div class="boxx-content custom-scroll">
            Box content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.details-coursework .boxx-content { padding: 0 0 0 0!important;  position: absolute; 
  bottom:0;  top: 0;  }
```

Since top: 0, '.details-coursework .boxx-content' should begin at the top of 'boxx details-coursework'.  The problem is that '.details-coursework .boxx-content' is beginning at class=right.  its parent element is 'boxx details-coursework', so thats where top should be set.  How do i fix this?

Here is some other css for boxx, but i don't think it is relevant:

```
.boxx { margin-top:11px;  }
.boxx:first-child { margin-top:0;  }
.boxx .boxx-content { background: #fff; padding:4px 18px; color:#a7a7a7; 
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight:300; border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;     }
```

Here is a jsfiddle.  I included some more code so it would be more visible what I am trying to do.  Look at the bottom-right block to see what I am trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ycGZ/

Comment: If you could provide a jsfiddle with all your code & styles, we could diagnose it further

Comment: Good idea, I'm making one now.

Comment: You have margin on your h2. Use this. `.boxx h2 {margin-bottom: 0;}`

Comment: @ginovva320, thanks, made the change.  the jsfiddle is updated.  Any one have any ideas?

Comment: If you remove that bottom margin, doesn't that make the child flush with the bottom of the parent? What is your desired result?

Comment: No.  The block should end where the "school awards content" ends.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Here's what I'm seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/3ycGZ/4/

Comment: Thats the same thing I see.  In the jsfiddle, the bottom right block ends before it should.  It should be longer and end at the end of "school awards content" but i can't get it to do that

Comment: Since your containers are floating, they're not contained within their parent, so I don't think you can achieve what you want with this setup. At a minimum, you'd have to set `overflow: auto;` on the `.details-bottom` element. After that, I'm not sure. Why not use a table...?

Comment: This is not tabular data, so a table would be inefficient.  I actually made some changes to the jsfiddle, and i think I'm very close.  What do you mean they're floating, aren't they nested inside the parent element?

Comment: If you inspect it in Firebug/Chrome dev tools, you can see that the div.details-bottom doesn't actually contain the two left and right elements, because they are floating. I've illustrated this here by giving that parent div a red background: http://jsfiddle.net/3ycGZ/6/

Answer (score 2):

In order to position the child relative to the parent, you need to declare that the parent's position is relative. I believe this should remedy your issue.

```
.boxx.details-coursework {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes it start at the top, but now it no longer goes all the way to the bottom...

Comment: You need to specify the `height` or `bottom` CSS attribute depending on what road you want to travel.

Comment: Thanks, tried it but for some reason height: 100% makes it go past the bottom of the parent element.

Comment: for some reason, i can't get both the top and the bottom to work at the same time.

Comment: I don't believe `top` and `bottom` are meant to be used together. I think they would conflict with each other.

Comment: It goes past the bottom because you're using `padding` in addition to `height`. The actual height will be the sum of these two values. So ideally, if you're setting the height in css, you need padding + height to be less than or equal to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

ginowa320 is right. Absolutely positioned elements use the first no-static positioned element as reference. You can see an example of this here: [W3Schools css positioning example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=absolute)

Comment: I'd recommend CSS-tricks take on the matter, http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/110-quick-overview-of-css-position-values/. Far better then w3schools on any day.