# make child div the same height as parent element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I have parent div with a class `row-fluid`, I want its child divs to be same height as the parent div.

```
<div class="row-fluid">    
    <div class="span2">            
    </div>      
    <div class="span7">              
    </div>       
    <div class="span3">                                       
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css code:

```
.row-fluid{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}


.row-fluid > .span2{
    float: left;
    width: 23.076923076923077%;
    background: red;
}

.row-fluid > .span7{
    float: left;
    width: 48.5%;
    background: yellow;
}


.row-fluid > .span3{
    float: left;
    background: green;
}
```

Here is the image that illustrates my divs:

[image]

The blue region is my parent div and the red, yellow and green region corresponds to its child divs.

Comment: Use `display:table` for the parent and `display:table-cell` for the children instead of floating them

Comment: does `.childDiv{ Height:100%;}` work?

Comment: @Pete --> I tried what you have said,  but it doesnt work.

Comment: @AlyssaGono try this - http://jsfiddle.net/y1kac2v7/

Comment: @AlyssaGono, what doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/cq7yhnwd/

Comment: Also have a look at: [How to make a floated div 100% height of its parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049783/how-to-make-a-floated-div-100-height-of-its-parent).

Comment: please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" as it means something else.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set a height on your parent div and `height: 100%` on your child spans?

```
.row-fluid {
  height: 300px;
}

.row-fluid > .span2,
.row-fluid > .span7,
.row-fluid > .span3 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Otherwise, you might wanne have a look at [this article](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks).

Comment: No, I cant do that my site must be responsive.

Comment: @AlyssaGono Check my edit then, maybe that article helps.