# Expand the div height to match the other one

Tags: html, css

Using CSS, how do I expand / fill the `<div>` height of both the right & left `<div>` **(determined by the `<div>` with the greater height)** with the `background-color` when there is no height set to the left or right `<div>`.

Depending on the amount of data supplied, the left `<div>` can be any height.

I have tried `height: 100%`, but this does not work.

**I have to use the float property - so I cannot use table / table-cell properties.**

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width) that expands the width, but the accepeted answer has a defined height value. All other examples seem to have a defined height value.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="photo">
        //image has max-height: 149px & max-width: 149px; assigned in the css file
        <img class="photo_dimensions" src="{{ name_details_photograph_url }}" />
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid;
}
.photo {
    height: 100%; 
    background:blue; 
    float:right;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;
    padding:2px;
}
.photo_dimensions {
    max-height: 149px;
    max-width: 149px;
}
.details {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Here is a visual display of what I currently have:

[image]

Comment: If your only concern is the background color below the `photo` why not just add background color to the wrapper div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the background to expand, set it on `.wrapper` instead.

[**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7qe2r06t/)

```css
.wrapper {
    background: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}
.photo {
    float: right;
}
.details {
    background: pink;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="//dummyimage.com/100"/>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q<br />Q
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate a table layout with non-table elements:

```
<div style="display:table">
    <div style="display:table-cell"></div>
    <div style="display:table-cell"></div>
</div>
```

That way the wrapped div's will be like table cells with same height.

Comment: Dasein A - My mistake - I cannot use tables as I must use the float property - I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `.wrapper` have `position: relative`.

Related: [How to make a floated div 100% height of its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049783/how-to-make-a-floated-div-100-height-of-its-parent)

Comment: Narawa Games - I have to have the two different background colours.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049783/how-to-make-a-floated-div-100-height-of-its-parent!

Answer (score 0):

***updated to redefine the .wrapper height to inherit a value from .details using jQuery***
Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0doo7L6L/1/

Is this what you're looking for? You must define a height for html & body for a height 100% to inherit a value

```
html,body {
height: 100%; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0doo7L6L/

Comment: Andrew Lemma - this will expand the height to more than the height of the tallest div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go with static hight div height. Please try following updated code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid;
}
.photo {
    height: 150px; 
    background:blue; 
    float:right;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;
    padding:2px;
}
.photo1{
    height: 150px; 
    background:red; 
    float:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;
    padding:2px;
}

.photo_dimensions {
    max-height: 149px;
    max-width: 149px;
}
.details {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:left;
}

//image has max-height: 149px & max-width: 149px; assigned in the css file
        
    
    
        Q
Q
Q
Q
Q
Q
Q
Q

```
</body>
```

Right side we have consider 2 Div
1) Full height & width and set the back-ground.
2) Place photo and its child DIV of first one.