# how to adjust aside height?

Tags: html, css, height

I just want aside can reach to the footer, and I set the height of aside as 100%, but it seems nothing happened.
my css:

```css
aside {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

my page is like:

[image]

So, how to let the gray aside reach to the footer?

Comment: Related: [How to make a floated div 100% height of its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049783/how-to-make-a-floated-div-100-height-of-its-parent)

Comment: If you provide a snippet with HTML and CSS you'll likely get more answers.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a flex layout to style your page.
Everything on the page could be inside a flex container `<div id="flex-outer">`

That container holds its content as 3 columns (header, container and footer) using the `flex-direction: column;` property. With `height: 100vh;` we make the page fill the screen.

The `<div id="container">` is another flex container itself, which holds your content and your sidebar. 
This container must fill the vertical space of your page (`flex-grow: 1;`), to make the footer remains at the bottom and the sidebar have a 100% height. You also probably want your sidebar to maintain its width (`flex-shrink: 0;`) and the content to fill the rest of the width (`flex-grow: 1;`).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#flex-outer {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: pink;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

aside {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 300px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

footer {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-outer">

 <header>This is the header</header>

 <div id="container"> 

  <div class="content">
    <p>This is the content</p>
  </div>

  <aside>
    <ul>
      <li>Categories</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>etc...</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>

 </div>

 <footer>This is the footer</footer>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks soooooooo much!

Comment: But if the height of flex-outfitter is 100%, it seems the aside can not fill the page anymore. Is their a way to solve this problem? cause the height of the container would not be a fixed number I think. Thank you!

Comment: this is my code in github:https://github.com/jinmanz/frontend-practice/blob/master/responsive/case2/case2.html

Comment: I think I know where is the problem. When I delete "height:100%" in aside, it can reach to the footer. Although I don't know why it happens.