# 100% of container height without modifying the container

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm writing some HTML to be inserted into a page. The current structure is something like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">left column</td>
  <td height="1">top row above content</td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td height="220">my content here</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have complete control over the table but **nothing** else. What I want to do is to have a the content fill the entire cell. I have gotten the width, but I can't get the height right.

Some things I have tried are:

- Setting the `height` to `100%`.
- Attributes like `height=200`.
- Giving the content absolute positioning. This unfortunantly made it fill the page instead of the cell.

The main problem that I haven't solved is because of the left column and content varying in height. When the left column is larger than the content it won't expand. Unfortunantly, fixed height iQsn't an option because it isn't responsive.

How can I make the content fit the the entire table cell?

Comment: In which browser doesn't `height: 100%` work? I tried FF 3.6, Opera 11, IE8 and Chrome 8, and they all happily fill the entire height of the td ( http://jsfiddle.net/nQfGV/ ).

Comment: This shows the problem (copied from above example and added some attributes from the actual page): http://pastebin.com/HnHumG2X

In both Firefox and Opera the blue box doesn't occupy its entire container because the large red box expands it.

Comment: What do you mean by "div fill the entire cell", do you mean content completely filling each table cell?

Comment: Also please see [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381/how-to-force-child-div-to-100-of-parents-div-without-specifying-parents-heigh?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an `iframe`? seems to me you could set the parameters of the `iframe` inside a table cell, div, as the `iframe` usually doesn't care where it is on the page.

Comment: Could you please add details on how to use this? Right now it doesn't make too much sense.