# div with min-height and the child div have the height of parent

Tags: css, html, height

Div with min-height and the child div have the height of parent.

Is it possible with only CSS or javascript is needed?

Example:

```
#main {
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu, #content {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#menu {
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}


<div id="main">
            <div id="menu">menu</div>
            <div id="content">content</div>
<div>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381

Answer (score 4, accepted):

may be you can give `position:absolute` to your `content div` to make it's equal height of it's parent

css:

```
#main {
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#menu, #content {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#menu {
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/hKttB/

**EDIT**
there are other option also . You can give `min-height` to your `content` div also if the content increase  the height of the `main` div also increase.

```
#content {
    height: 100%;
    min-height:300px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/SRJrF/2/

Comment: Mmh, the solution may work, but what about the content becomes higher? You cut it with `overflow:hidden`. Why then specifying a `min-height` rather than `height`? Thought the requirement for `min-height` implied the content can be higher than 300px and should grow in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

In this case I forced same min height for the child div when there is less content.
If content exceeds, the automatic overflow.

```
#content {
    min-height: 300px;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color: green;
}
```

This is how we have content div in our nested master page.
Hope same will work for you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think its not possible.

but you can try something like this. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SRJrF/)

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height:300px;
    min-height:300px;
}

#menu,
#content{
    float: left;
    display:inline;
    width: 50%;
    position:relative;
}

#menu {
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

also please read this [min-height](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-height)
regarding min-height.