# Set min-height to 100% as a child of a container with a min-height of 100%

Tags: css

TL:DR; Is it possible to set a child of `min-height:100%` to `min-height:100%`?

My `#body-container` is a full-width container while my `.bg-container` is just a 920px container.

[As pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLYmpx?editors=110)
As snippet

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

#body-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-container {
  width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="body-container">
  
  <div class="bg-container">
    foo bar
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [div with min-height and the child div have the height of parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503649/div-with-min-height-and-the-child-div-have-the-height-of-parent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just add `height:100%` and `overflow:auto` to the `#body-container`:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
#body-container {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: red;
}
.bg-container {
  width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="body-container">

  <div class="bg-container">
    foo bar
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Indeed. I forgot to add `overflow:auto`. Answer and snippet updated. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrYwbv?editors=110

Comment: The `overflow: auto` is crucial here – I was wondering why it did not work for me, but I did not have it set :/ Great answer, helped a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest work-around would be to use [viewport percentage units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths). In this case, `100vh` would work since the element is relative to the viewport anyways. You can always use `calc()` to displace the value if the element isn't positioned relative to the viewport.

In doing so, you don't need to set a `height`/`min-height` on any of the parent containers either:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: black;
}
#body-container {
  background-color: red;
}
.bg-container {
  width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="body-container">
  <div class="bg-container">foo bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only drawback I see to this solution is that `vh` isn't supported in some older browsers.

Comment: @j08691 Support looks pretty good to me ;) http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units I guess that's up to the OP... at least my answer doesn't add a scrollbar to the element.. like yours does.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, Flexbox

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/RrwVdj?editors=110)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}
#body-container {
  width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.bg-container {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="body-container">

  <div class="bg-container">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Where'd the red background disappear to?

Comment: Behind the `bg-container...isn't that what's supposed to happen?

Comment: I don't think so. The OP's bg-container extends the full width as a normal div would. Might not be a big deal for them.