# make <div> fill <td> without scripts

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-9

Yes, this is one more question about good old `div` inside `td` but without scripts.

`td`'s width is defined in pixels.

I want a `div` (and its inner input) fill the whole `td`. I made it work in Chrome, but failed in Firefox and IE9. It's a total mess there. (I don't care about IE6-8)

Here is the snippet I'm testing on: http://jsfiddle.net/K5D9z/37/.
Is there a generic solution to this?

**EDIT**

Though I didn't specify previously, I expect the content of some table cells to grow in height and expand some rows. In IE and FF `height: 100%` means element will always have the container's initial height specified in css: http://jsfiddle.net/K5D9z/51/. All of the answers have this issue.

**UPDATE**

As has been noted in a comment there seems to be no pure css solution. So I resorted to the script setting height in a `style` attribute for every `td` according to its calculated height: http://jsfiddle.net/K5D9z/54/.

Comment: Dropping the `input`'s positioning stuff (`position`, `top`, etc.), and giving it a height of `100%` and a width of `auto`, seems to work for me on Firefox 17.0.1. (I haven't checked other browsers.)

Comment: You cannot make the child element fill 100% of the parent's height unfortunately.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381/how-to-force-child-div-to-100-of-parents-div-without-specifying-parents-heigh

Comment: I've seen this, but that answer is about making it only _look_ like all the columns are 100% height. But when it comes to the actual borders of the content containers they are still only as tall as their content. So it doesn't help the `input` tag fill its container entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `position:absolute` from `.test-cell div, .test-cell input`. This is causing the `input` to be removed from the normal flow of content, so it won't remain in the `td` where it is supposed to. This, along with changing `height` and `width` from `auto` to `100%` should give you the solution you are looking for.

```
.test-cell div, .test-cell input{
  display: block;
  /* position: absolute; Don't use this style */
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* Don't need these, because it goes along with position absolute
     top:0;
     left:0;
     bottom:0;
     right:0;
  */
  background-color: green;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5D9z/65/)

Comment: I expanded the case in an edit to the question. Your solution doesn't work in IE (at least in IE10) if I add more content: http://jsfiddle.net/K5D9z/51/.

Comment: @rgripper what do you want the final result to look like

Comment: Like in Chrome - both input fields grow according to their rows.

Comment: Strange, but in IE it seems to do the trick :). Gotta check FF and if it's ok, I'll mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

CSS:

```
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td
{
    padding:0;
    border: 1px Solid gray;
    height: 120px;
    width: 100px;
}

.test-row 
{
    background-color: red;
}

.test-cell div, .test-cell input
{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    background-color: green;
}
```

​
DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/K5D9z/47/

Comment: There is a problem in FF and IE9-10 again if the content's height in the first column is bigger than the td's height. The whole row grows but div sticks to the original height defined in css.

Comment: Sorry about that, made a change to my initial post.