# How do I extend my sidebar the full height of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chickendance/szTcq/2/)

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="span2 sidebar">sidebar</div>
            <div class="span10 content">content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been searching Google for the past few hours trying to find a solution. I don't think I can do [Faux Columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns) because the site is built on Bootstrap, so the sidebar width will change depending on the width of the browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Force Child Div to 100% of Parent's Div Without Specifying Parent's Height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381/how-to-force-child-div-to-100-of-parents-div-without-specifying-parents-heigh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must first set both the `html` and `body` to `height: 100%`. Then, if you don't have a navbar, also the `sidebar` to `height: 100%`.

If you are using a non-fixed navbar, you must use `absolute` positioning.

Absolute positioning is anyway another way to solve this. After having the height of `body` and `html` set to 100%, set `bottom: 0` and `top: 0`, together with `position: absolute`. And you must know that the `absolute` positioning is computed relative to the closes parent having `position: relative`.

Comment: Thanks! Works great!