# How to give a floating sidebar 100% height of its parent?

Tags: html, css, styles

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyE4B/)

I want a layout like above but I don't want to manually assign height to my sidebar(as i am doing now). I want the sidebar height to be 100% respect to its parent element i.e content-area

```html
<header> </header>
<div class="content-area">
<div class="left-sidebar"></div>
<div class="main-area"></div>
<div class="right-sidebar"></div>
</div>
<footer> </footer>
```

my css

```css
.content-area {
min-height: 310px;
background-color: #bbb;
}
.left-sidebar {
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: 310px;
background-color: #abcdef;
}
.right-sidebar {
float: right;
width: 50px;
height: 310px;
background-color: #abcdef;
}
```

Comment: If you give a specific height to the container you can just do a `height: 100%`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381/how-to-force-child-div-to-100-of-parents-div-without-specifying-parents-heigh

Comment: @nsawaya i saw that question. but i am specifying parent's div height here

Comment: @Shubendra you are specifying a minimum height. Try actually specifying the actual height. i.e. `height: 310px;`

Comment: @Shubendra, Check the answer posted by default.

Comment: @AnaMaria can you help me clearing my doubt i posted in that answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `min-height` does not work the same way that `height` does, so as far as your sidebars are concerned the height is 0. You have two options:

1.) Specify a height on your container `div` and then set the sidebars to have a `height: 100%`. [Here is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyE4B/3/).

2.) Set your containing `div` to have `position: relative` and the sidebars to have `position: absolute`. This should allow the `height: 100%` to work with `min-height`. However, with this solution you cannot use the `float` property, so for your right sidebar you will need to set `right: 0`. [Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyE4B/25/) for a working example.

Comment: @Default i have to write content in main-area div. by using absolute positioning my content goes hidden. and when i write anything the right-sidebar also slides down

Comment: @Default is there any advantage of using float on left-sidebar? as you have used absolute positioning i can assign it as left: 0;

Comment: No, sorry I accidentally left that float in there. `left: 0` would be the right way to go. I'm looking into the other issue you mentioned.

Comment: That was my bad, you'll also have to give your `.main-area` class `position: absolute`. I've updated the fiddle in my answer to demonstrate with content. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.right-sidebar { float: right; width: 50px; height: auto; background-color: #abcdef; position:relative;}
```

Try this ... Is this what you're shooting for?

Comment: It doesn't help your fiddle, but I have done something similar to fix my sidebar.

Answer (score -1):

give height property to the ".content-area" class and then apply 100% height to the sidebar. for ex:

```
.content-area {
min-height: 310px;
background-color: #bbb;
height: 500px;
}
.left-sidebar {
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #abcdef;
}
.right-sidebar {
float: right;
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #abcdef;
}
```