# How to get vertical borders to grow with content

Tags: css

How can I get both vertical borders to grow equally regardless of content height in any column?

```
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
  <div style="min-height:500px;width:100%;margin:auto;border-top:2px solid #333;border-bottom:2px solid #333;">
    <div style="min-height:496px;float:left;width:23%;border-right:2px solid #333;padding:0 5px;">
      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">1</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">2</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="min-height:496px;float:left;width:33%;padding:0 5px;">
      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">1</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">2</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="min-height:496px;float:left;width:33%;border-left:2px solid #333;padding:0 5px;">
      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">1</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">2</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">3</a>
      </div>


      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">1</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">2</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">3</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">1</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">2</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">3</a>
      </div>


      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">1</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">2</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">3</a>
      </div>


      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">1</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">2</a>
      </div>

      <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <a href="#">3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: height:100% for the columns

Comment: I just tried that but it does nothing

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381/how-to-force-child-div-to-100-of-parents-div-without-specifying-parents-heigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the floated columns, in my case I used an added element (but there are [MANY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing) ways to do so), and also have `height:100%` for each column

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/misetego/1/edit)

On a side note, you should really use an external style sheet and classes, managing inline code is very difficult as is styling each element individually

Comment: Thanks Zach. I can see that it works, thanks. I plan to move all the css to a stylesheet once I get it all laid out the way I want it.

Comment: @NaN That seems counter intuitive and slow to me, but whatever floats your boat, at least until someone is telling you how to do it (:

Comment: You're right, I would agree that it's counter intuitive to do everything inline but the client continually changes his mind and it just seemed like a faster way for me to manage everything in the mean time.

Comment: Zach, are you still around? I'm a little confused here because I've copied what you did on jsbin and it looks exactly the same as what I had before. I can however see when it runs in jsbin that it looks perfect. Why whould this be?

Comment: @NaN [Let's go to a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/48178/room-for-zach-saucier-and-nan?tab=general#)

Comment: I don't... What you did looks great on jsbin but if I copy everything and paste it into a new html file, the border on the left is shorter than the one on the right. I'm also using the same browser, so I'm at a loss