# How to make div same height as parent (displayed as table-cell)

Tags: css, html, multiple-columns

I got a container div containing three child divs (vary in content) - each as tall as the tallest one. I managed this by setting the container to display:table and the child divs to display:table-cell etc.

Everything worked just fine, until...

I inserted a new div inside one of the child divs and tried to make it height:100% - so it would stretch to the same height as its parents, but that did not work.

**Please see my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkG5A/**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">
        a<br />a<br />a
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="content">
            a<br />a<br />a
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container {
    display: table;
}
.child {
    width: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Another option is to set your child div to `display: inline-block;`

```
.content {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: table;
}
.child {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    a
    <br />a
    <br />a
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    a
    <br />a
    <br />a
    <br />a
    <br />a
    <br />a
    <br />a
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">
      a
      <br />a
      <br />a
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bkG5A/3/)

Comment: interestingly, this does not work in IE 10 and FF 28 (even my solution does not work in IE 10 and FF), can't understand these 2 browsers at all.

Comment: I have same issue. Display table not working on all browsers.

Answer (score 8):

You have to set the `height` for the parents (container and child) explicitly, here is another work-around (if you don't want to set that height explicitly):

```
.child {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  position:relative;
}

.content {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkG5A/1/)

Comment: Also, I reckon it's a bad idea to use absolute positioning to solve this.

Comment: @Chris don't understand why it did not work for you, I've of course tested it. And it's not a bad idea at all, you may not understand how absolute positioning works at all

Comment: You're right about the code working fine - did not work for me due to some terrible caching in Firefox. But I'm still not convinced that absolute positioning is a good solution. Here is a reason why: http://jsfiddle.net/bkG5A/5/ - added padding to the div.

Comment: @Chris looks like absolute positioning is just not good **in this case** where we have to deal with the `table-cell` layout, which is I think very complicated. The solution you have in fact does not work in FireFox 28 and IE 10 (not sure what versions you have, but those version are the latest ones). There is only solution in which we set the `height` explicitly for the `container` and `child` (as I mentioned in the answer) which can work OK for Chrome, Opera, and FireFox but not for IE 10 (so weird), this problem is hard to solve cross-browser although it looks like simple indeed.

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right. I agree that this is a very simple task, but though hard to solve in css. I guess this has to be solved in JS after all? Like with the jQuery.equalHeights plugin.

Comment: I thought for a moment that this was going to work for me but in practice I realized that the absolute position takes it out of the flow and the div I had floated next to it no longer floats where I want it to.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this CSS:

```
.content {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-table;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkG5A/4/)

Comment: That worked fine :) But I prefer reinders solution better, as the div is already within a table - and then it might not be the best solution to make it a table within a table.

Answer (score 0):

The child can only take a height if the parent has one already set. See this exaple : [Vertical Scrolling 100% height](http://codepen.io/drew7721/pen/rrNPPN)

```
 html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .header{
        height: 10%;
        background-color: #a8d6fe;
    }
    .middle {
        background-color: #eba5a3;
        min-height: 80%;
    }
    .footer {
        height: 10%;
        background-color: #faf2cc;
    }
```

```js
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*="#nav-"]').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 500);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #a8d6fe;
}
.middle {
  background-color: #eba5a3;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #faf2cc;
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#nav-a">got to a</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#nav-b">got to b</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#nav-c">got to c</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="header" id="nav-a">

  </div>
  <div class="middle" id="nav-b">

  </div>
  <div class="footer" id="nav-c">

  </div>
```