# Why does height: 100% on a child element not apply when the parent element has a min-height/max-height value but no height value?

Tags: html, css

Say we have the following set up:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

It's clear that the `container` element is rendering with a height set to `300px`, but the `child` element has no height whatsoever, despite being set to `100%`.

When the height of the `container` element is set to even `1px`, the `child` element will suddenly fill the entire `container` with a height of `300px`.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: 1px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

The `container` element is clearly rendering at `300px` even without height being set so why does it require setting the height before the `child` element actually applies it's `height: 100%`?

Edit: To be clear, I'm not looking for a solution to having the child height take up the entire parent element, I would just like to understand why this behaves like this.

Comment: Related - [How to force child div to be 100% of parent div's height without specifying parent's height?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22712489/1366033)

Comment: The reason is probably you haven't defined a boundary i.e. a set limit to how much your child element so the child element defaults to  setting wrapping the content and not expanding to the full height can occupy, try setting a max height to the parent, or you can use flex boxes in your css

Comment: Adding max height on parent doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the first case, you don't have any height defined so it's clear that the precentage height on child will fail.

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not **specified explicitly** (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

`min-height` is only a boundary and the height of your element still depend on its content. If you will have one that exceed `300px` the element will have more than `300px`

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding:10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes change{
   from {
     height:100px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

---

In the second case you have specified a height so the precentage will work but the height calculation is a bit tricky since we also have `min-height`

> The following algorithm describes how the two properties influence the used value of the 'height' property:
>
> 1. The tentative used height is calculated (without 'min-height' and 'max-height') following the rules under "Calculating heights and margins" above.
> 2. If this tentative height is greater than 'max-height', the rules above are applied again, but this time using the value of 'max-height' as the computed value for 'height'.
> 3. If the resulting **height is smaller than 'min-height'**, the rules above are applied again, but this time using **the value of 'min-height' as the computed value for 'height'**.

In the second case, it's like you explicitely defined `height:300px` and percentage will consider this value. In this situation, even if the content is bigger the parent element will not grow and you will have overflow. You can even define a height equal to `0`.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: 0;
  padding:10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px; 
  animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes change{
   from {
     height:100px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Same logic will happen with `max-height` but in this case the height need to be very big

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  max-height: 300px;
  height: 99999px;
  padding:10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px; 
  animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes change{
   from {
     height:100px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you are intrested you can transform your logic using flexbox and you will be able to do what you want without having to set an explicit height.

Relying on the default stretch alignment on the cross-axis

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
  display:flex;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  /* height: 100%;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Or using the `flex-grow` property instead of height in main axis:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  flex-grow:0.8; /* this is 80%, use 1 for 100% */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS grid can also handle this

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:1fr;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```