# min-height vs height when 100% applied to viewport height

Tags: css

Today, I encountered an issue with percentage height when applied with viewport height.

```css
.min-vh-100 {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.vh-100 {
  height: 100vh;
}
.h-100 {
  height: 100%;
}
.bg-cover {
  background-color: red;
}
.bg-container {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- This doesn't work -->
<!-- The .bg-container doesn't fill the .bg-cover -->
<div class="min-vh-100 bg-cover">
  <div class="h-100 bg-container"></div>
</div>
<hr />
<!-- This works -->
<!-- The .bg-container fills the .bg-cover -->
<div class="vh-100 bg-cover">
  <div class="h-100 bg-container"></div>
</div>
```

I have checked multiple doc links [width height keywords](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#width-height-keywords), [percentages](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#percentages) but couldn't find the reason behind this.

So, I would like to know the key reason behind this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, I found the [reason](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-height):

Percentage:

> Specifies a percentage for determining the used value. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, **the percentage value is treated as '0' (for 'min-height')** or 'none' (for 'max-height').

---

From the statement above, the simple fix for this issue is to apply positions:

```css
.min-vh-100 {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.vh-100 {
  height: 100vh;
}
.h-100 {
  height: 100%;
}
.bg-cover {
  background-color: red;
}
.bg-container {
  background-color: blue;
}
.position-relative {
   position: relative;
 }
.position-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; /* or: left: 0; right: 0 */
}
```

```html
<!-- Now, this works -->
<!-- The .bg-container fills the .bg-cover -->
<div class="min-vh-100 bg-cover position-relative">
  <div class="h-100 bg-container position-absolute"></div>
</div>
<hr />
<!-- This works -->
<!-- The .bg-container fills the .bg-cover -->
<div class="vh-100 bg-cover">
  <div class="h-100 bg-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The point being that, since the element is absolutely positioned, it is taken out of the flow, and has no effect on the height of its containing block. Which means that there's no circular dependency between the heights of the two divs.

Comment: this is wrong, you need to look at the height definition not the min-height one:https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property ... the part you made in bold is not related to your issue. It's relevant when you use `min-height:100%` on the element that will compute to 0 if the parent doesn't have any height specified

Comment: @TemaniAfif My answer is correct. This is the  issue with min-height but not height.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Also, if your statement would be correct, then there'd not be any issue coz parent has 100vh height.

Comment: parent has *min-height* not height and you are setting percentage to height so the section explaining percentage on min-height cannot be the relevant one

Comment: The min-height 100vh set the the parent 100vh but child 100% is taken as 0 because parent is applied with min-height. So, the issue is with the min-height not height.

Comment: *The min-height 100vh set the the parent 100vh* --> it set the min-height of parent to 100vh to its height that's why the height of the child is not working because the parent height is not set explicitely (add height:0 to parent and it will work)

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. But I think I'm right.

Comment: @Alohci But it takes 100% height of parent height though.

Comment: found another duplicate with better explanation and examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58548742/8620333 (you have two now that should make things clear)