# min-height and min-width - where in MDN doc does it tell you this behaviour?

Tags: html, css

From this I deduce that a child using min-width to any relative value (like % or em) will try and be the exact same length as its parent.

However using min-height it'll try and stretch to be exactly on the minimum mark.

If this is true, where in W3C documentation - or better yet the MDN documentation - does it tell you this?

```html
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;">
    <div style="min-width: 50%; min-height: 50%; background-color: blue;">Hello</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it will stretch but won'nt shrink ;) A block is 100% of width avalaible and expand it's height from content

Comment: Another confusing thing was this in MDN "“If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage value is treated as 0.” Would anyone be able to demonstrate what this means exactly?

Comment: if you use % , then it requires a parent with a known height to calculate it, else it is XX% of NULL . Is this what bothers you ? (only html can do without) if the parent has no height set in CSS , then there is no reference to work from . Javascript can look for an height and retrieve it, css can not :(

Comment: maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58548742/8620333