# Placing divs/tables

Tags: php, html, css

I got some tables that are filled with data to generate tables, now everything works fine, but i cannot get these tables on the places i want them...

when i load the page they look fine:
[image]

but when i make one of them larger they dont stay so nice in place:
[image]

any way to keep them together even when one on the other side is made bigger?
I tried this with floating and aligning, and then i dont know any other options.

**EDIT:** 
note that my tables are being generated.
Like if the user wants to add 2 graphs to the site, he gets 2 of this tables, and within this tables he can choose how much variables he want to show in it and needs to input query's for it.

So the height of the tables is never really the same, and can change all the time.
that why i am having problems finding a solution

Comment: Can you please show your code along with the screenshots?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Force Child Div to 100% of Parent's Div Without Specifying Parent's Height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381/how-to-force-child-div-to-100-of-parents-div-without-specifying-parents-heigh)

Comment: Give the height of each table as inherit in css.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use tables why don't you enclose all 4 of them into a 5th table?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width="50%"> put here table A</td>
<td width="50%"> put here table B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> put here table C</td>
<td> put here table D</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Style the outer table to have red borders and some pading on its cells and you are set