# CSS DIVS and Auto height

Tags: html, css

this is driving me insane and I am obviously missing something which i cannot seem see.

I have some nested div - below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Immigration Reform</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="Text/css" href="css/test.css" media="screen" />

<div class="HeaderWrap">
    <div class ="Header">
        <div class="HeaderLogo"></div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="BodyWrap">
    <div class="Body">  
        <div class="BodyLeft"></div>
        <div class="BodyRight"></div>   
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="FooterWrap">
    <div class="Footer">
        <div class="FooterPicture"></div>
        <div class="Footer1"></div>
        <div class="Footer2"></div>
        <div class="Fotter3"></div>
        <div class="Footer4"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Not matter what i do, the .Body height does not automatically adjust when the child divs grow past the min-height.

CSS CODe

```
.HeaderWrap,
.BodyWrap,
.FooterWrap{float:left; width:100%; border:1px solid yellow; clear:both;}

.Header,
.Body,
.Footer{width:960px; border: 1px solid green; margin:0 auto; clear:both;}

.Header{height:227px; background:url("../Images/man-with-flag-1.png") no-repeat;#box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 black; z-index:-1; clear:both;}
.HeaderLogo{float:left; height:100px; width:150px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000000; background:url("../Images/visa.png") no-repeat; position:relative; right:-45px; bottom:-165px; border:5px solid white; z-index:999;clear:both;}

.BodyWrap {border: 1px solid red;}
.Body {position: relative; border: 1px solid green; min-height: 450px; clear:both;}

.BodyLeft{float:left; height:900px; #min-height: 900px; border:1px solid yellow; position: relative; #top: -90px; z-index:-1;background:#b1b6bc; #box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0  black; width:26%; clear:both;}
```

What i am missing? thank you.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to [clear floats](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/) after `.bodyLeft` and `.bodyRight`.

Comment: I already have clear:both on both those sections.  Did i miss something?

Comment: Clearing floats within a floated element's CSS definition generally won't work. You've got to do it before/after the floated elements. I usually use the "[clearfix class](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/#method-3-the-clearfix-class)" method applied to the parent of the floated elements.

Comment: This did not work at all.  addeded .clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}   and mofified  html - no go.

Comment: oopps. the clearfix need tobe applied to the parent not the child!  Excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.Body` element does not expand vertically because its children are floated, [which removes the children from the normal document flow](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/understanding-css-floats/).

In order for `.Body` to expand with the height of its children, clear floats after the floated elements. The method I usually use to do this is [Nicolas Gallagher's "Micro Clearfix Hack"](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) (or a variation of it). He sets up a class that can be applied to the floated element's parent. Something like this:

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}
```

```html
<div class="Body clearfix">
    ...
</div>
```

Test it below:

```css
.HeaderWrap, .BodyWrap, .FooterWrap {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    clear:both;
}
.Header, .Body, .Footer {
    width:960px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
}
.Header {
    height:227px;
    background:url("../Images/man-with-flag-1.png") no-repeat;
    #box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 black;
    z-index:-1;
    clear:both;
}
.HeaderLogo {
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    width:150px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000000;
    background:url("../Images/visa.png") no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    right:-45px;
    bottom:-165px;
    border:5px solid white;
    z-index:999;
    clear:both;
}
.BodyWrap {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.Body {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
    min-height: 450px;
    clear:both;
}
.BodyLeft {
    float:left;
    height:900px;
    #min-height: 900px;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    position: relative;
    #top: -90px;
    z-index:-1;
    background:#b1b6bc;
    #box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 black;
    width:26%;
    clear:both;
}



.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
 
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
 
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}
```

```html
<div class="HeaderWrap">
    <div class="Header">
        <div class="HeaderLogo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="BodyWrap">
    <div class="Body clearfix">
        <div class="BodyLeft"></div>
        <div class="BodyRight"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="FooterWrap">
    <div class="Footer">
        <div class="FooterPicture"></div>
        <div class="Footer1"></div>
        <div class="Footer2"></div>
        <div class="Fotter3"></div>
        <div class="Footer4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the code here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b634rL8v/). You can add `display: table-cell` to `.Body`:

```
.Header, .Body, .Footer {
    width:960px; 
    border: 1px solid green; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    clear:both; 
    display: table-cell;
}:

display: table-cell;
```

But it does not work for IE7.

Also for your reference: [How to Force Child Div to 100% of Parent's Div Without Specifying Parent's Height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381/how-to-force-child-div-to-100-of-parents-div-without-specifying-parents-heigh)

Comment: This worked but broke my centering of the page.   is there a method to adjust?  right now is use  "margin:0 auto" all sections to  center.