# How can I make two equal height columns in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>Line</p>
            <p>Line</p>
            <p>Line</p>
            <p>Line</p>
            <p>Line</p>
            <p>Line</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>Line2</p>
            <p>Line2</p>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see two columns are not equal and each has a height content.

I tried to make this example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12807/) but clearly we did ... but I put the link

I tried to import bootstrap but not working

I also found [this](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/) example in the documentation bootstrap but failed to implement it

Can you help me please implement this example (if possible in jsdfidle)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting read: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Force Child Div to 100% of Parent's Div Without Specifying Parent's Height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381/how-to-force-child-div-to-100-of-parents-div-without-specifying-parents-heigh)

Comment: Bootstrap, or any 'normal' framework won't support this. Also, you don't want to do this with any kind of javascript. No, you want to use flexbox. Relevant article; http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback (only use JS if the browser is really outdated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this to your CSS:

```
.row [class*="col-"]{
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
}

.row{
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12810/

Or use flexbox:

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12811/

Comment: I think not you understand
divs  left and right must be in line and have the same height regardless of content.

We div The red is higher than blue

Comment: if they must be inline regardless of the viewport width then change the col class to `col-xs-6` instead of `col-md-6`.

Comment: Try the other solution I provided below, I came across the similar issue and It worked for me pretty well, Its a very simple to use JS code.

Comment: it looks like it will work, but if OP wants the columns to stay inline then he needs to use the appropriate grid class anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height%20#answer-19695851

Answer (score 0):

This works for me well, hope it will resolve your issue of equalizing height.

**Just apply class "eq_height" in the DIVs you want to make equal and include the code below in your page**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var highestBox = 0;
        $('.container-fluid .eq_height').each(function(){  
                if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
                highestBox = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $('.container-fluid .eq_height').height(highestBox);

});
</script>
```

This will take the height of biggest div and equalize according to it.

Comment: We can use this and keep the inline style too.